# How to merge strings together in a loop in powershell

Tags: powershell

My aim is to send an automated message which contains all the strings from my loop.

I got a `$body` variable which is something like

> This message shows you how much `$size` of your `$project` is used

I want to merge these strings into one variable which I can send through mail, but either it sends in separated mails or only the last loop remains.

## Code:

```
Enter-PSSession *computer*

$attributes = (Get-FsrmQuota | select Description, Size, PeakUsage)

foreach ($attribute in $attributes)
{
    $counter = $attributes.Count
    $descr = $attribute.Description
    $size = $attribute.size
    $tomb = @($descr.Split(";"))
    $mail = $tomb["1"]   # user mail adress
    $project = $tomb["0"] # user project
    $name = $mail.Split("@")[0] #username
    $firstName = $name.Split(".")[0]  
    $lastName = $name.Split(".")[1]
    $size = [Math]::Round(($attribute.Size)/1Gb,1).ToString() + " Gb" #storage size
    $usage = [Math]::Round(($attribute.Usage)/1Gb,1).ToString() + " Gb" #storage usage
    $percent = [Math]::Round((($attribute.Usage / $attribute.Size)*100),2).ToString() + "%"
    $projname = $array["2"] #project name

    
    for($i=1; $i -le $counter; $i++)
    {
        $ITBody = "The $projname project uses $size."
        $array+=$ITBody 
    }
}

write-host $array
```

Got the results duplicated soo many times

Comment: Share your code and we will be able to help you.

Comment: foreach $attribute in $attributes
{
$descr = $attribute.Description
$array = @$descr.split(";")
$proj = $array["1"]
$size = $attribute.Size

$body = "The $project project uses $size data"

}

I need the $body-s into one string

Comment: Putting code in comments isn't a good thing to do as it's hard to read. Instead, edit your question and add code.

Comment: What's the purpose of the `for` loop?

Answer (score 6):

```
$array = @()

foreach ($attribute in $attributes){
    $projname = $attribute.ProjectName
    $size = $attribute.Size


    $array += "The $projname project uses $size GB"
}

$body = $array -join "`n"
```

The `$array = @()` part initializes the `$array` variable as an empty array.

In your foreach-loop, you can directly add the built string to that array.

With `` $array -join "`n" `` you concatenate all elements from the array with a newline between the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can just combine them in to one variable by adding it to one another.

```
$combinedVariable = $body + $size + $project
```

Or you can combine them as a message

```
$combinedVariable = "This message shows you how much $size of your $project is used"
```

You can also add every variable to an array to pile up in the loop and later on use them separately

```
$array += $combinedVariable
```

If this is not what you ask for, please provide further details of your code and we can help you better.

Comment: I added $array+=$combinedBody into my code. It is closer to working, but somehow the loop doesn't stop when all of the datas are stored

Comment: You have to decide when do you want the loop to stop. if you want to stop when `$combinedBody` is `$true`, then put that as a condition , `if ($combinedBody){break}` for example

Comment: I tried something like 

$i=0
for($i=1
     $i -le $counter
     $i++){
       $combinedBody
     }
break

but it still shows way too many data

Comment: currently I have 6 bodies which needs to be merged to one email (kind of a report), but it's gonna be about 100-200 in the near future

Comment: "$i=0 for($i=1 $i -le $counter $i++){ $combinedBody } break" - This will loop through incrementing $i from 1 until it equals less than the number in $counter.  Well it would but the format is wrong, it should be:  "for($i=1; $i -le $counter; $i++).

Comment: @Robert please post the exact code you're using ant the output